# Running mongod on a location other than default crashes mongod seconds after starting mongod process?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

```
OS      Ubuntu 16.04
mongod  4.0.3
```

I was trying to delete mongodb completely from my system. So I delete files I thougth were related to mongodb. Now I reinstalled mongodb according the instructions given on official website. It is working fine if I use it with default path. But when I try to use run mongod with a differnt dbpath.

The `monogd` process starts and terminated in some seconds with the error

```
aditya@aditya-Latitude-3450:/data/appdb$ sudo -u mongodb mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/appdb --logpath /data/appdb/mongodb.log --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1 
2018-10-10T22:52:12.238+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2018-10-10T22:52:12.238+0530 I CONTROL  [main] log file "/data/appdb/mongodb.log" exists; moved to "/data/appdb/mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-22-12".
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I check the log file and it gives the error.

`No such file or Directory /data/appdb/journal`

I have also tried to run it with `--nojournal`, but error persists

The is the mongo [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BqMevnIUDyK8Bb1LgX2c_K3alLHsTElq/view?usp=sharing) and also given as text here:

```
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15146 port=27017 dbpath=/data/appdb 64-bit host=aditya-Latitude-3450
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.3
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/appdb", wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { cacheSizeGB: 1.0 } } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/data/appdb/mongodb.log" } }
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-10-10T22:51:55.543+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1024M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-10-10T22:51:56.541+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1539192116:541899][15146:0x7fe6b95dfa00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2018-10-10T22:51:56.725+0530 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.053+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-10-10T22:51:57.054+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 69d27978-76da-47c4-b9c6-cdea6935196e
2018-10-10T22:51:57.426+0530 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0
2018-10-10T22:51:57.429+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: bf0a63e8-ed89-4fa6-a536-8da9cc29b3c1
2018-10-10T22:51:57.709+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/appdb/diagnostic.data'
2018-10-10T22:51:57.709+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-10-10T22:51:57.709+0530 I STORAGE  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] createCollection: config.system.sessions with generated UUID: 158b221f-f8e5-41d2-9965-f4aa74326b08
2018-10-10T22:51:58.173+0530 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index on: config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 }
2018-10-10T22:51:58.173+0530 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh]     building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2018-10-10T22:51:58.174+0530 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2018-10-10T22:51:58.174+0530 I COMMAND  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] command config.$cmd command: createIndexes { createIndexes: "system.sessions", indexes: [ { key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 } ], $db: "config" } numYields:0 reslen:114 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } } } protocol:op_msg 465ms
2018-10-10T22:52:02.841+0530 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger error (2) [1539192122:841103][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __directory_list_worker, 48: /data/appdb/journal: directory-list: opendir: No such file or directory Raw: [1539192122:841103][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __directory_list_worker, 48: /data/appdb/journal: directory-list: opendir: No such file or directory
2018-10-10T22:52:02.841+0530 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger error (2) [1539192122:841182][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __log_prealloc_once, 469: log pre-alloc server error: No such file or directory Raw: [1539192122:841182][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __log_prealloc_once, 469: log pre-alloc server error: No such file or directory
2018-10-10T22:52:02.841+0530 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger error (2) [1539192122:841196][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __log_server, 1015: log server error: No such file or directory Raw: [1539192122:841196][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __log_server, 1015: log server error: No such file or directory
2018-10-10T22:52:02.841+0530 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1539192122:841205][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1539192122:841205][15146:0x7fe6b1572700], log-server: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2018-10-10T22:52:02.841+0530 F -        [thread1] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 408
2018-10-10T22:52:02.841+0530 F -        [thread1] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2018-10-10T22:52:02.855+0530 F -        [WTJournalFlusher] Fatal Assertion 28559 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 64
2018-10-10T22:52:02.855+0530 F -        [WTJournalFlusher] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2018-10-10T22:52:02.856+0530 F -        [thread1] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
 0x55ba8343f071 0x55ba8343e289 0x55ba8343e76d 0x7fe6b7d7b390 0x7fe6b79d5428 0x7fe6b79d702a 0x55ba81a7d7bb 0x55ba81b719f6 0x55ba81be2ef9 0x55ba81a08072 0x55ba81a08492 0x55ba81c41ef2 0x7fe6b7d716ba 0x7fe6b7aa741d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"23CE071","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"23CD289"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"23CD76D"},{"b":"7FE6B7D6A000","o":"11390"},{"b":"7FE6B79A0000","o":"35428","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7FE6B79A0000","o":"3702A","s":"abort"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"A0C7BB","s":"_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"B009F6"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"B71EF9"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"997072","s":"__wt_err_func"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"997492","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"55BA81071000","o":"BD0EF2"},{"b":"7FE6B7D6A000","o":"76BA"},{"b":"7FE6B79A0000","o":"10741D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.0.3", "gitVersion" : "7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.15.0-34-generic", "version" : "#37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 28 10:44:06 UTC 2018", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "55BA81071000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5CEC4F75328106C4E3A4535157518B166B4D38FD" }, { "b" : "7FFE815D7000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E911E0D9CAD9386D8F1660DDFE0D8D401EDCC397" }, { "b" : "7FE6B917A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D192460BE804CC9B9807E6D49834431CBF20E9A" }, { "b" : "7FE6B8F5F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6EF73266978476EF9F2FD2CF31E57F4597CB74F8" }, { "b" : "7FE6B8B1B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "250E875F74377DFC74DE48BF80CCB237BB4EFF1D" }, { "b" : "7FE6B88B2000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "513282AC7EB386E2C0133FD9E1B6B8A0F38B047D" }, { "b" : "7FE6B86AE000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8CC8D0D119B142D839800BFF71FB71E73AEA7BD4" }, { "b" : "7FE6B84A6000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "89C34D7A182387D76D5CDA1F7718F5D58824DFB3" }, { "b" : "7FE6B819D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DFB85DE42DAFFD09640C8FE377D572DE3E168920" }, { "b" : "7FE6B7F87000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7FE6B7D6A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CE17E023542265FC11D9BC8F534BB4F070493D30" }, { "b" : "7FE6B79A0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B5381A457906D279073822A5CEB24C4BFEF94DDB" }, { "b" : "7FE6B93E9000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D7B6259552275A3C17BD4C3FD05F5A6BF40CAA5" }, { "b" : "7FE6B776D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E09D3783AD1D0BBCD3204FA01E4EF6D756E18F57" }, { "b" : "7FE6B7551000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D1CC1204D6B6D33BD1D2C5A2A0516A2234322CF" }, { "b" : "7FE6B7307000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DB5180B568097E2A4690A5B40D36BD134C893FEE" }, { "b" : "7FE6B70F8000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D3B183C41F02C7CD18F906AAFD19C69C850F1CEB" }, { "b" : "7FE6B6EA7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA0EC53E16B3AC6BDC56EAEFE1BFECDDC395FB2E" }, { "b" : "7FE6B6C8D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D9BD4CE26E45EF16075C67D5F5EEAFD8B562832" }, { "b" : "7FE6B695D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3CE893F6D1382C2C7648DCCB06E71B1C7E0861CC" }, { "b" : "7FE6B672A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B11678F560199547DCF726384EA39153EE0DFABF" }, { "b" : "7FE6B64F4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D6B36C5A463EE0FA84FDD6D5FD3F7726EDB90D54" }, { "b" : "7FE6B6274000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7B3533D5998D20EE1A1BE3F87789B69041E7F620" }, { "b" : "7FE6B5FA2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "16E3DBC6D048145939BB43BBFD7954D27421B00F" }, { "b" : "7FE6B5D73000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AEB4C08FC47F86C475E9D3996DFE5E9B403ACEBF" }, { "b" : "7FE6B5B6F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E16CB57F699E215A2A8D4EFEF90883BC749B12D" }, { "b" : "7FE6B5964000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DF3219B89E86920E901BAC4A80AA60F2B6134588" }, { "b" : "7FE6B5749000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "96BCC7EB28D81B1469EED6F24FC083CBD58577BC" }, { "b" : "7FE6B5508000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1FE877BE52A424D0636AFD4D35BB330E41D6E0F3" }, { "b" : "7FE6B52A4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A0E2D03FF5CF65937F4425D4EFD4D655243809EB" }, { "b" : "7FE6B5091000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E07E186694852D8F69459C6AB28A53F8DA3CE3B6" }, { "b" : "7FE6B4E8D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3364D4BF2113C4E8D17EF533867ECC99A53413D6" }, { "b" : "7FE6B4C84000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "73A8EADBC85860662B24850E71D4AFBE22C33359" }, { "b" : "7FE6B49FA000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "59E742306A4EA2872E061ECCE92F35FADDA75357" }, { "b" : "7FE6B4758000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E5C159E415406AE79D21056D752BA949C408B5B1" }, { "b" : "7FE6B4525000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7D15576E1F096614D360784E4A01A1F5FAF908C9" }, { "b" : "7FE6B430F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "481DB33C28D88E43DA6BED65E1A7599407D4D818" }, { "b" : "7FE6B4107000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9D9C958F1F4894AFEF6AECD90D1C430EA29AC34F" }, { "b" : "7FE6B3EDE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "57E25072866B2D30CF02EBE7AE623B84F96FA700" }, { "b" : "7FE6B3CCF000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F6F1B4E9F89B716C4A0BA5819BDFFAF4A13EFB91" }, { "b" : "7FE6B3A84000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C60082E3BB78D0D42868D9B359B89BF66CE5A1A7" }, { "b" : "7FE6B37AF000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D9782BA023CAEC26B15D8676E3A5D07B55E121EF" }, { "b" : "7FE6B3577000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7BDD51353D50310FFA1587E4AA01B40ABE32D582" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55ba8343f071]
 mongod(+0x23CD289) [0x55ba8343e289]
 mongod(+0x23CD76D) [0x55ba8343e76d]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7fe6b7d7b390]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7fe6b79d5428]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x16A) [0x7fe6b79d702a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj+0x0) [0x55ba81a7d7bb]
 mongod(+0xB009F6) [0x55ba81b719f6]
 mongod(+0xB71EF9) [0x55ba81be2ef9]
 mongod(__wt_err_func+0x90) [0x55ba81a08072]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x3F) [0x55ba81a08492]
 mongod(+0xBD0EF2) [0x55ba81c41ef2]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x76BA) [0x7fe6b7d716ba]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fe6b7aa741d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

The permissions for the files are given below

```
aditya@aditya-Latitude-3450:/data$ ls -l
total 28
drwxrwxrwx 3 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 10 22:52 appdb
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb     0 Oct 10 23:23 automation_restore_started
drwxrwxrwx 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 10 20:12 diagnostic.data
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 17640 Oct 10 20:12 mongodb.log
aditya@aditya-Latitude-3450:/data$ cd appdb/
aditya@aditya-Latitude-3450:/data/appdb$ ls -l
total 296
drwxrwxrwx 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 10 22:52 diagnostic.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb nogroup 15003 Oct 10 22:52 mongodb.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1446 Oct 10 20:12 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-42-07
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1411 Oct 10 20:12 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-42-11
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1446 Oct 10 20:12 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-43-04
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 15038 Oct 10 20:13 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-49-26
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 17783 Oct 10 20:19 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-49-31
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1411 Oct 10 20:19 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-49-52
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 19611 Oct 10 20:20 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-52-46
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 15003 Oct 10 20:22 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T14-59-55
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1635 Oct 10 20:29 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T15-01-47
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1635 Oct 10 20:31 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T15-01-56
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  3402 Oct 10 20:31 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T15-02-02
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  3394 Oct 10 20:32 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T15-02-38
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  3429 Oct 10 20:32 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T16-26-29
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1411 Oct 10 21:56 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T16-45-21
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1411 Oct 10 22:15 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T16-45-32
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  1446 Oct 10 22:15 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T16-45-54
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 15787 Oct 10 22:16 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T16-47-27
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 15130 Oct 10 22:17 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T16-50-34
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 15003 Oct 10 22:20 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T16-52-40
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  9036 Oct 10 22:23 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-05-40
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb nogroup 15574 Oct 10 22:35 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-08-20
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb nogroup 14993 Oct 10 22:38 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-11-54
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb nogroup 14993 Oct 10 22:42 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-19-07
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb nogroup 15003 Oct 10 22:49 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-19-18
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb nogroup 15003 Oct 10 22:49 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-21-55
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb nogroup 15241 Oct 10 22:52 mongodb.log.2018-10-10T17-22-12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had manually deleted the `/data/appdb/journal` file therefore it was unable to find that.

I found out this, when i tried a diffrent dbpath `/data/appdb2`, it ran smoothly.